# Why isn't a vector of smart pointers to an item implementing an interface covariant with that interface?

Tags: c++, covariance, contravariance

Why isn't a vector of smart pointers covariant with an interface that item implements? e.g. if I have a vector of pointers to a dog, why can't I use that as a vector of pointers to iAnimal?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct iAnimal
{
    virtual std::string speak() const = 0;
};

struct iMammal : public iAnimal
{
    virtual std::string speak() const = 0;
    virtual int legs() const = 0;
};


struct Dog : public iMammal
{
    std::string speak() const
    {
        return "WOOF!";
    }
    int legs() const
    {
        return 4;
    }
};


void giveMammals(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<iMammal>> an)
{
    for (const auto x : an)
    {
        x->legs();
    }
}

void giveAnimals(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<iAnimal>> an)
{
    for (const auto x : an)
    {
        x->speak();
    }
}

int main()
{   
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Dog>> vec1 = { std::make_shared<Dog>() };
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<iMammal>> vec= { std::make_shared<Dog>() };
    giveAnimals(vec);
    giveMammals(vec1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Receive the vector as a vector of `iAnimal`s; 2. Insert a `Cat` inside said vector (you can, `Cat` is an `iAnimal`); 3. Come back to the caller and ask for everyone in the vector to bark. See the issue?

Comment: You should really be passing your vectors by *reference* or `const`-*reference*. There don't appear to be good reasons to pass-by-value in your examples.

Comment: Mutability is a real pain

Comment: On the other hand, you could have a templated `giveAnimals` and forget about category theory.

Comment: You'll take my f-bounded polymorphism when you pry it from my cold dead hands

Comment: The vectors do not inherit from a common type for covariance to occur.

Comment: It's not only mutability but also difficulty of implementing covariance (and contravariance) in presence of multiple inheritance.

Comment: C# has co-variance and contra-variance, C++ has only (limited) co-variance for return type of virtual methods.

Comment: @Galik inheritance is conceptually separate from subtyping

Comment: If you need f-bounded polymorphism you know where to find it. C++ isn't that kind of place.

Comment: @n.m. what about `template <template <typename, typename...> class ForwardRange, class MammalPtr> void giveMammals(ForwardRange<MammalPtr> mammals) { /* as above*/ }`?

Comment: @Caleth which comment you are responding to? :)

Comment: You could have the caller convert appropriately, `giveAnimals(vector<shared_ptr<iAnimal>>{vec.begin(), vec.end()});`.

Comment: @n.m. C++ not having f bounded polymorphism. It just doesn't do it with `virtual`

Comment: I don't quite understand what your example has to do with f-bounded polymorphism. Simple bounded polymorphism is parametric polymorphism with bounds. f- adds recursion to that. C++ doesn't even have parametricity, much less bounded parametricity (class templates are not parametric types).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that the kind of code you're proposing could be easily exploited to do a lot of nasty things. For one example, let's see how, trivially, if this code were legal (it's not) it would be possible to insert a `Cat` into a vector of `Dog`'s.

```
struct Cat : public iMammal {
    std::string speak() const
    {
        return "meow.";
    }
    int legs() const
    {
        return 4;
    }
};

void giveAnimals(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<iAnimal>> & an) {
    //This, on its own, is perfectly legal given the type that `an` is.
    an.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Cat>());

    for (auto const& x : an)
    {
        x->speak();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Dog>> vec = { std::make_shared<Dog>() };
    giveAnimals(vec);//Uhhhh.......
    for(auto const& dog_ptr : vec) {
        dog_ptr->speak();//These are not all going to bark!
    }
}
```

`std::vector` (and other similar library constructs) prohibit this kind of conversion exactly to prevent mistakes/errors like this.

Comment: That's a bit unexpected, but still tame. `Dog` could have a non-virtual member function that does not exist in `Cat`, and *that* will ruffle some whiskers upon calling it.

Comment: I would go with "don't allow" instead of "forbid", as it's intentional non-action instead of deliberate action. The distinction is not important for the consumer, but for the implementer, and few are only ever on one side of that.